# Apply condition and replace NA values with mode

Tags: python, pandas, missing-data

I need to apply the condition and then replace all na values with mode.
but when I run the below command, it replaces all the values with mode even if Seen_StarWars='NO'.

Can you tell me a replacement so I don't have to use any loops.

```
Rate_char=['Han_Solo','Luke_Skywall','Princess_Leia','Anakin_Skywalker','Obi_Wan_Kenobi','Emperor_Palpatine','Darth_Vader','Lando_Calrissian','Boba_Fett','C-3PO','R2_D2','Jar_Jar_Binks','Padme_Amidala','Yoda','Char_Shot_First','Expanded_Universe','Fan_of_star_trek_franchise']
```

I am using the following command :

```
data_drop=data_drop.loc[(data_drop['Seen_StarWars']=='YES')].fillna(data_drop[Rate_char].mode().iloc[0])
```

Comment: Edit your title by putting the command in the question, and selecting proper words to describe the question. Also, please share a `df` with sample input and expected output.

Comment: 1. You wrote *when I run the above command*, but now your post does not include this command (it was in the first version of the title). 2. Include the content of the source DataFrame.

Comment: Would be nice if you could show us some sample data..

Comment: This might be of help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40619445/how-to-replace-na-values-with-mode-of-a-dataframe-column-in-python/40621330